# SSRS drill down report not displaying in report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have an SSRS report (drill down report) built and it works fine through the browser. However when we open the same report through the report viewer (WPF application - report viewer hosted as windows forms host), the drill-down functionality is not visible. The report is shown without the drill down part.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
The issue was that the report in print layout format does not display the expanders. On changing the report layout to normal, the expanders were seen and worked as expected.